# Show that $f ≡ 0$ for an entire function f

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Suppose $f ∈ H (\Bbb C)$ such that
> $$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |{f(re^{i \theta})}|d\theta \leq r^{\frac{17}{3}}$$ for every $r > 0$
> Show that $f ≡ 0.$

Here's what I tried:

For an entire function we have a Taylor series expansion,
$$f(z)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nz^n $$

Using the Contour Integral formula and applying Cauchy's estimate, we have
$$|a_n|=\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(re^{it})}{(re^{it})^{n+1}}ire^{it}dt\right|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f(re^{it})}{(re^{it})^{n}}dt\right| \leq \\ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\left|\frac{f(re^{it})}{r^{n}}\right||dt|\leq 
\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{r^{\frac{17}{3}}}{r^n}=\frac{r^{\frac{17}{3}}}{2\pi r^n}$$

Now $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}$ $a_n=0,\forall r> 0.$

So we have $f(z)=a_0$ But now how do I show $f ≡ 0?$ Also, is my approach correct or there is another way I should do this?

Comment: So you meant for *all* $r>0$, not just for *some* $r>0$? What happens when $r\to0$?

Comment: The hypothesis is only for one value of $r$. You cannot let $r \to \infty$. Any small positive constant function satisfies the hypothesis so the question is wrong.

Comment: This exercize is wrong. Consider $f \equiv 1$ a constant function, and $r$ big enough. Then clearly the inequality is satisfied, but $f$ is not the constant function zero.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq yes it was a mistake. It is supposed to be for every r>0

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes it is supposed to be for every $r>0$ not for some $r>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly derived that
$$
|a_n| \le \frac{r^{17/3}}{2\pi r^n} = \frac{1}{2\pi} r^{17/3 - n}
$$
for all $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ and all $r > 0$. Now the “trick” is to consider not only the limit for $r$ to infinity, but also the limit for $r$ to zero, depending on the index $n$:

- For $0 \le n \le 5$ is $17/3 - n > 0$, and therefore
  $$ 
  |a_n| \le \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{2\pi} r^{17/3 - n} = 0 \, .
  $$
- For $n \ge 6$ is $17/3 - n < 0$, and therefore
  $$ 
  |a_n| \le \lim_{r \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} r^{17/3 - n} = 0 \, .
  $$

Comment: but how do I finally  conclude that $f≡0?$. I now have $a_n=0$ so $f(z)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nz^n=a_0$

Comment: @esquire: The above calculations works for all $n \ge 0$, so you get $a_0 = 0$ as well.